# Any way to preload a script executed in an iframe later?

Tags: javascript, iframe, preloading

I have a huge script which is executed inside an iframe, so I was thinking to preload the script when the page starts being loaded and then execute it only when the frame is loaded.

Is it possible?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at
HeadJS http://headjs.com/ or 
LabJS http://labjs.com/ or other JavaScript loaders.

Comment: I'm using LabJS but I can't see the option to do that, so not sure if it's possible

Comment: true preloading is only possible in IE at the moment (and activated by logic added to LABjs 2.0). other browsers require "cache preload" hacks, which are brittle and not recommended. but true preloading (as IE does it) is likely coming soon to spec and other browsers.